# Mouse issue-- critter trapped in interior wall

Tags: walls, mice

Sleepless nights due to a presumably large and very noisy mouse in our bedroom wall... what are the best ways to kill/remove/pinpoint its location? Not certain, but think it may be trapped and unable to get out of the wall.
Is it possible to kill and just leave to decompose? (in which case, we need a way to mask the odors until it dissipates.) We have glue traps all over the house. Mice are a perennial problem--but this is the 1st time it has ever happened before the weather turned cold. Can't use the preferred solution of a hungry female cat because my daughter is deathly allergic to cats. If I can pinpoint its location, I was thinking perhaps drilling a small hole in the drywall, and spraying ether into it..hoping the fumes might overcome the critter. But not sure if this would even work--or if the risks outweigh the potential benefit.
We have also set a have-a-heart cage trap in the attic, in case it is a larger critter (racoon, muskrat, or other) and is not trapped in the wall.
Any suggestions/ideas appreciated. We have already caught at least 5 mice this summer (none in our 2nd story). I'd put a black snake in the basement, if I could find one and it wouldn't make its way into the living area. That's how desperate we are.

Comment: If trapped inside a wall, would probably have very small section to travel/move.  Walls usually ~16 inch sections closed off from each other(modern build).  The bad news is that wood and drywall usually do not keep mice/rats trapped that well for long, they eat though them.   Should have a close look on the outside of the house for any small openings/holes(1/4 inch) and close/block them off.

Comment: Very unlikely that it's trapped, IME. Might be a squirrel (I call them "rats with fluffy tails") Ether is highly flammable and thus not a very good plan, IMHO, even before the stink. Cutting a hole the size of a small (mouse and squirrel size) have-a-heart might work, with the trap butted up to it.

Comment: Youtube has videos of people seating large tires with either and a spark.  Very high on my list of things not to do.

Comment: In my experience, the traditional strong-spring-wire-loop mousetraps work well if baited with thick peanut butter. Place them right along the corner between wall and floor or wall and shelf, as mice instinctively run along such passages rather than out in the middle of the floor.

Comment: The Ether solution sounds like making a big bomb! One spark and the critter would be gone. You can get some poison and put it in peanut butter and drop a small amount in the wall.

Comment: If they are making noise, it is more than one, making nest or multiplying.

Comment: Glue traps are a horror. They torture the animal until it dehydrates to death. That kind of apathy to suffering and sociopathy is not a thing to teach a child.  Regular old mousetraps work just fine: quick and merciful kill. And you can reuse them (though of course the manufacturer would prefer you not). Place them alongside, not on, mouse highways. They don't put fruit stands in the middle of the road.

Comment: Follow-up: I bought some auto-reset type 'bucket' traps. Will follow-up with info on how well it works...  We've had fairly decent luck in the past with glue traps. But this one must be a lil' smarter than your ave. mouse.